# Accessing Docs in Secure Google Docs Bucket via PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I have a project where I want to store docs in a Google Cloud Bucket.  These docs should not be publicly accessible.  Right now, I am able to place documents in the bucket, but I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve them while keeping the bucket secure.  *If I open up access to "allUsers", the docs load fine.  However, I want these docs to only be accessible if they are using the system.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to do this, but I can't seem to come up with an answer on Google.

I have hit dead ends for days now, so please help!  *To be clear, I do not have any code to show.   Thanks

Comment: When a bucket is created data is not generally [publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#code-samples) and they have by default [access control mechanisms](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) based on IAM permissions or ACLs set in place. What do you mean by keeping the bucket secure? Is there a reason why using the PHP code samples for [downloading](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) objects is not suitable for your setup?

Comment: @DanielOcando is right, you should be able to download your files if you set up the authentication properly (the service account with the proper permissions) and use any of the examples exposed in the links previously shared by Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @DanielOcando is right if "they are using the system" means that they are accessing directly GCP. For this answer, I'm assuming that "your system" is an application that you are developing or something similar.

For this approach, the safest method is to use [signed URL's](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) This will let your users access your documents without the need to have a Google account, you can also set an expire time for this URL's to control how much time the user can be using the documents.